# increasing magento efficiency by loading outside of looping strctures

Tags: collection, sql, query, object

Is there a good method for me to work around needing to load these products within the foreach loops?  This is found in so many places within my codebase.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
            $similarParts = $this->getSimilarParts();
            $productIds = $this->getSimilarProductIds($similarParts);
            foreach($productIds as $product){
                $childProduct=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product);
                $url = Mage::getBaseUrl() . $childProduct->getUrlKey() . '/p' . $this->getRelatedSku($childProduct). '/';
                echo $this->getRelatedSku($childProduct);
            }

            public function getSimilarParts(){

                $categories = $this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds();
                $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
                $match = false;

                foreach($categories as $categoryId){
                    $category = $collection->load($categoryId);
                    $categoryName = $category->getName();
                    $startWith=substr($categoryNumber,0,1);
                    $zeros = $strpos($categoryNumber,'0000');
                    if(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() === "default"){
                        if($zeros == false && $startsWith == '6'){
                            $match = $category;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return $match;
            }

            public function getSimilarProductIds($similarParts) {

                $productIds = array();
                $productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($similarParts);
                $count = 0;

                foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
                    if ($product->getId() !== $this->_getProductId()) {
                        if ($count < 5) {
                            $productIds[] = $product->getId();
                            $count++;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return $productIds;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the product collection to load all products with a single query. For example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
```

This will load the products but won't include all product attributes. To add more attributes you can use addAttributeToSelect. E.g.

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('size');
```

Then you can simply loop through your collection and use your product object, no further queries will be made.

Answer (score 1):

**"One collection to rule them all."**

I'd highly recommend reading Vinai Kopp's "Pre-loading for Scalability" Blog post as it will answer a lot of the questions you have. While it's not a direct answer to the code you've posted. It should give you a general idea on how to approach each problem, as every instance will vary.

- http://vinaikopp.com/2014/06/09/preloading-for-scalabiliy/

Magento has some details about this very issue (that runs pretty rampant) along with a tool to help scan code bases for the issues like these.  I would also recommend using the PHPCodeSniffer ruleset they provide as well during development and 3rd party module code audits/reviews.

- http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf
- https://github.com/magento-ecg/magniffer
- https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard